# CSS : How to have an input field auto adjusting its width

Tags: css

I have a div called wrapper. It is centered horizontally using the margin property. The width of that wrapper is fixed.Inside that wrapper I have an a tag followed by an input field. What I am looking for is to have the width of the input field auto adjusting to the remaining width on the right (until the border of wrapper). I would like to avoid defining the width in pixels. I tried few thing but nothing is working (width auto or 100% for instance). Hope to be clear and hope someone can help.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/72sPT/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <a>this is a button</a>
   <input type="text"/>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: blue;
}
```

​

Comment: Sorry check it here http://jsfiddle.net/72sPT/2/

Comment: the think is that i want the width to take automatically the entire remaining space on the right side. And with your solution if I put 100% there is a line break and the input field is placed on the next line...

Comment: Try it on an html document I think the line break happens because of the limited space in jsfiddle.

Comment: See my answer here regarding flex and flex-grow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52975265/1599699

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wrap the input tag in another div, you can do:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: blue;
}
#wrapper a {
    float: left;
}
#wrapper div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello Kenneth. thank you. Your proposition is working. Strange thing is that when setting the width to 100% there is an overflow. The right border of the input is hidden. To avoid that I have to set it at 99%. But that is fine with me. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Marc, that's because of the box model/sizing used (where width does not include padding and border). You could set `box-sizing: border-box` to include those and get a fitting input when `width: 100%`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to not mess with your `<a>` tag, then you can float your input to the right:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npsfB/)

```
#wrapper {
width:600px;
margin:10px auto;
background:blue;
}

#wrapper input {
 float:right;
width:70%;    
}
```

Comment: hello jofry. thanks for tryig to help but again, as I said, I was looking for the input field to adjust to the total remaining space. Not just a part of it... Thanks anyway