# Input text & button with span inline

Tags: html, css

we must display an input-field and a button with an inner span on the same line.
Button resp. its inner span must have `width:auto`, the input text must fill the remaining width.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1xfxpm55/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <button> <span>Auswählen</span>

    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}
input {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
button {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
}
```

Thanks for any hints

Comment: what you expecting as result

Comment: I'm not clear with what you trying to achieve.

Comment: Input text and button must fill 100% width, button must be width:auto because the inner text can be taller or wider...

Comment: your CSS is missing some `;`

Comment: Change `width:100% display: table; `to    `width:100%; display: table;` and `width: 100% float: left;` to `width: 100%; float: left;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773517/style-input-element-to-fill-remaining-width-of-its-container and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476423/how-to-make-an-input-field-have-100-width-minus-the-width-of-the-submit-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658479/css-how-to-have-an-input-field-auto-adjusting-its-width

Comment: these are answers without span in button, which we need to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the button in a div with a small width:

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
*:before, 
*:after {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.c1 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right:10px;
}
input{
    width:100%;
}
.c2 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left:10px;
    width:1%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="c1">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
        <button><span>Auswählen</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: already near on our code, thank you! The c2 has too much height at the moment though... will be able to resolve that :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use javascript? If I get the question right, the input text field has to fill the entire line - the width of the input button, correct? Here is a sugestion:

```
function getRemainingWidth(button, elm) {
    elm.style.width = "calc( 100vw - " + realWidth(button) + "px)";
    alert(elm.style.width);
}

function realWidth(elm) {
    var width = elm.offsetWidth + 
        parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'), 10) +
        parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue('padding-right'), 10) + 
        parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue('margin-left'), 10) + 
        parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue('margin-right'), 10);

    return width + 10;
}

window.onload = getRemainingWidth(document.getElementById('btn'), document.getElementById('textfield'));
```

Made a working jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/1xfxpm55/4/ (its an update of your provided demo).

Comment: no, we'd better not use JS for this...

Comment: look at PoseLab's solution, it works fine. if you remove the padding values you get the same effect as this but without javascript.